# En VisualStudio, al pulsar un botón iniciar ProgressBar y cuando llegue al 100% mostrar texto en un textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

estoy haciendo un programa simple en Visual Basic pero por algún motivo el código no me funciona,quiero que al pulsar un botón se inicie el ProgressBar,cuando llegue a 100% muestre una palabra en un textbox, lo hago de la siguiente forma

En el Botón pongo el código

```
Timer1.Start()
```

Luego añado un Label que dice Código: y un TextBox,y aparte un timer,en el timer pongo el código

```
ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Hola Mundo!"
    End If
```

y no funciona, no se si será cosa de Visual Studio ¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El codigo parece correcto.

Se me ocurren dos cosas:

En el boton, establece la propiedad Maximun al valor que quieras antes de iniciar el Timer.

El Timer, inicialo con Timer.Enabled = true antes de hacer el Timer.Start()

Depura el codigo para ver si llegas al Maximum o si por el contrario no llegas.

Te paso el codigo, en C# pero podras cambiarlo de lenguaje facilmente.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);

        if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
            textBox1.Text = "final";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Si quieres la solucion, te paso aqui el enlace:
https://www.cbamultimedia.com/ftp/PruebaProgressBar.zip